# Qt - Is this pass by reference?

Tags: c++, qt, pass-by-reference

If we write the following in `Qt`as an argument to a function: `QString &tableName`

Does that mean we are passing by reference?

Thanks.

Comment: `&` returns the adres of your variable, right?

Comment: @Kevin Not in this case.

Comment: @Neil: Could you explain what it means in this context? I'm confused!

Comment: @Kevin It's a reference.

Answer (score 6):

Strictly speaking, that is a function *parameter*, not a function *argument*. The parameter is the variable declared inside the function's parameter list; the argument is the value passed to the function by the calling function. So parameter `QString &tableName` is passed by reference. But as a function argument, `&tableName` would mean "the address of `tableName`".

**Updated:** As requested, here is a code sample to clarify the distinction:

```
void f (double y) ;
f (99.0) ;
```

`double y` is a parameter declaration; it resembles a variable declaration. `y` is a function parameter.

`99.0` is a function argument; it is an expression, that must be convertible to type `double`.

Comment: Is there some well-defined terminology for the case?

Comment: I mean, where does the described difference between 'parameter' and 'argument' originate from? Is it some sort of convention, or it has some firmer ground?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the distinction has been around since Kernighan & Richie (if you're under 50, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is pass-by-reference in C++. You could also write `QString const & tableName`, if you don't want to have the very possibility of accidentally changing tableName.

Comment: You can equivalently write `const QString &tableName`.

Comment: @Rob, that's a pure accident :D

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Tip: make it `const` if you don't want it to change.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, like most non-trivial Qt basic types, QString is a lightweight container object that implements "copy on write" semantics.  So the only reason to pass one by reference is if your function wants to modify the caller's copy, and there is never any reason to pass one by const reference (unless you do not know much about Qt).

Comment: That is largely a matter of taste.

Comment: I'd say there's more than taste against this. Thread-safe "Copy on write" requires atomic counters, which may be far less efficient than just passing a reference.